# Spark Scala SQL making a new Column based on another column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe as

```
EmpId  EmpName   Salary   SalaryDate 

 1     Amit  1000.0   2016-01-01  

 1     Amit  2000.0   2016-02-01  

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-03-01   

 1      Amit     2000.0   2016-04-01  

 1      Amit     3000.0   2016-05-01  

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-06-01
```

I want to add a new column named prevSal which will have data of Amit's previous row value of salary

Expected Output:

```
EmpId  EmpName   Salary   SalaryDate prevSal 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-01-01  null 

 1      Amit     2000.0   2016-02-01  1000.0 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-03-01  2000.0  

 1      Amit     2000.0   2016-04-01  1000.0 

 1      Amit     3000.0   2016-05-01  2000.0 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-06-01  3000.0
```

Also, I want a new column named NextSal which will have data of Amit's next row value of salary.
Expected Output

```
EmpId  EmpName   Salary   SalaryDate prevSal  nextSal 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-01-01   null   2000.0  

 1      Amit     2000.0   2016-02-01  1000.0  1000.0 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-03-01  2000.0  2000.0 

 1      Amit     2000.0   2016-04-01  1000.0  3000.0 

 1      Amit     3000.0   2016-05-01  2000.0  1000.0 

 1      Amit     1000.0   2016-06-01  3000.0   null
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I don't know how to do it, I haven't tried any method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement LEAD and LAG in Spark-scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37754704/how-to-implement-lead-and-lag-in-spark-scala)

Comment: no this doesn't answer it

Answer (score 1):

As [ggordon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4307136/ggordon) pointed with their comment, this is a simple case of using `lag` and `lead` to access the previous and next row's value based on the row that's being currently scanned each time.

The key for these functions to work is basically enforcing an order of rows within the DataFrame to fully determine which row comes before and after another. For this we use one case of Spark's [window functions](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-sql-window-functions/) named `orderBy`. `orderBy` in your DataFrame should be used on a column that will be used as reference to order the rows. Since your rows are kind of already ordered by the `SalaryDate` column, something like this would be sufficient:

```
val w = Window.orderBy("SalaryDate")
```

About the `prevSal` column, the usage of `lag` can be seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#lag) and based on that information we can use the window function from above to access the previous row's `Salary` value with something like this (first argument is the name of the column to search upon, second argument is the offset aka how may rows back do we want to go each time):

```
lag("Salary", 1).over(w)
```

`lead` works the same way, but for the forward values of the `Salary`. `lead`'s usage can be seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#lead):

```
lead("Salary", 1).over(w)
```

So all of this can look a bit like this (given that `df` is the name of your DataFrame):

```
val w = Window.orderBy("SalaryDate")

df.withColumn("prevSal", lag("Salary", 1).over(w))
  .withColumn("nextSal", lead("Salary", 1).over(w))
  .show()
```

So the end result would look like this:

```
+-----+-------+------+----------+-------+-------+
|EmpId|EmpName|Salary|SalaryDate|prevSal|nextSal|
+-----+-------+------+----------+-------+-------+
|    1|   Amit|  1000|2016-01-01|   null|   2000|
|    1|   Amit|  2000|2016-02-01|   1000|   1000|
|    1|   Amit|  1000|2016-03-01|   2000|   2000|
|    1|   Amit|  2000|2016-04-01|   1000|   3000|
|    1|   Amit|  3000|2016-05-01|   2000|   1000|
|    1|   Amit|  1000|2016-06-01|   3000|   null|
+-----+-------+------+----------+-------+-------+
```

In case you want to make `prevSal` and `nextSal` specific for each employer (e.g Amit to have a different set of `prevSal`/`nextSal` than let's say John), you simply change the window function by firstly partitioning the table by `EmpName` and then ordering it by `Salary`:

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("EmpName").orderBy("SalaryDate")
```